# Avoiding Array Recursive Set (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

```
Class MyClass
{
    public int[] MyArray
    {
        get {return MyArray;}
        set
        {
            if (value == null) { MyArray = new int[2] { 0, 0 }; return;}
            else { MyArray = value; return;}
        }
    }
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.MyArray = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
    }
}
```

In my class I have an `int[]` and I need to do things with `value` in `set` except when I try to make a new instance of `MyClass` I get a stack overflow.

When I put a breakpoint on the constructor and on `set` it reveals `myArray = new int[2] {0, 0};` in the constructor calls the set method and once the set gets to line `myArray = value` it calls the set method again. This loops for some time, then it throws a stack overflow exception. I've tried putting a `return;` right after the assignment but it doesn't reach the return.

Any enlightenment on using the set method for an array would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `get` and `set` have a body, you need a backing field which you are missing.

```
class MyClass
{
    private int[] _myArray;

    public int[] MyArray
    {
        get {return _myArray;}
        set
        {
            if (value == null) { _myArray = new int[2] { 0, 0 }; }
            else { _myArray = value; }
        }
    }
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.MyArray = new int[2] { 0, 0 };
    }
}
```

In this code, there is the private field `_myArray` which is being used as the backing field for the property.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is You are pointing to the same memory space:

```
public int[] MyArray
{
    get {return MyArray;}
    ...
}
```

Accessing property `myArray` will go to access Your property `myArray` which will lead to accessing the same property!

---

Answer to this is using `private variable`, which can be directly written only from Your class. And the `public property` will just access this variable.

Like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int[] _myArray;
    public int[] MyArray
    {
        get { return _myArray; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) { _myArray = new int[2] { 0, 0 }; return; }
            else { _myArray = value; return; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

More details abou properties can be found for example [on DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/property) or [MS Official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).